# How to check if a field exists using iMacro

Tags: imacros

I Need to check to see if an html field exists in a website using iMacro plugin for firefox.
If the field does not exist, then I need to perform a different opperation

Answer (score 2):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:C
```

`TAG POS=` Which A class do yo want.

`Type=` To find your text in that class

`ATTR=` What do want from that class. (TXT, HREF...)

`TXT(or something different):` You can use `*` to find anything in class. İt marks the object. Or you want to search example:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=TXT:I<sp>am<sp>a<sp>text.
```

This code means find the first bold item which is in text:I am a text, and mark it.

Comment: I am trying to do a similar operation, i need to find a text but if the text is not found then I need to click a button on the page, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Ahmet, the code above gets the content or raises an error if not found. I need to know if the field exists or not.