# auto highlight/copy

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, highlight, imacros

There's a game I play on firefox, and there's a way to recruit soldiers to me and to other players, all I have to do is click on the same word of an image, like this:

[image]

Once I clicked the image disappears and this message appears, saying I've recruited a soldier for that player.

[image]

On page source this element is where's this message is located:

```
<div id='population_increase'>You have just increased player's population to 128.933.</div>
```

After that I have to manually copy this message, "*You have just increased player's population to 128.933.*" and paste on the textfield of this, located on another tab/site

[image]

This would be the proof, that others players need, to know I've clicked on them.

So since I've to do this about twenty times a day, I'd like to ask if anybody knows any way to help to do this procedure. Like copy that text I need to highlight and copy manually, or just highlight that to me press ctrl+c. I've tryied looking for javascript/greasemonkey scripts without success and imacros too.

The perfect automate procedure would be get that text I need to copy and throw to the textfield on the another tab, click send data and change tab to the other link that would be opened once send data was clicked, but I believe that would be very difficulty or impossible to do it, so any help would be welcome!
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty involved task.  Parts of this are possible with a script (like Greasemonkey), but for full automation (not counting clicking the image), you'll need to write a browser extension.  This is not something that we do, from scratch, here at SO, for you.  But you can [break the problem into bite-sized chunks and ask about those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a CSV file after that you can paste your text to textarea from csv. You dont have to copy that.

```
TAG POS=(you edit) TYPE=(you edit) ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=yourfile.csv
```

Or, you can set that text as a variable in first tab, then you can change your tab to 2 and paste the text to your textarea. This is better.

---

Here, look at my answer for html-tag relation. [Html-Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128519/how-to-check-if-a-field-exists-using-imacro/6658174#6658174)

Or you can read [Tag-Html from wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAGs_and_HTML)

Comment: how exactly I do that?

Is this imacro code?

thanks in advance

Comment: TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ResultsForm ATTR=NAME:r_text CONTENT=You<SP>have<SP>just<SP>increased<SP>user's<SP>population<SP>to<SP>132.801.

highlighting the text that should be set, after the manual click, I get this code from imacro.

Comment: Can you share that game's link? Because you didnt get the correct position of tag. You must write that position by yourself. Not recording it.


Read that: http://wiki.imacros.net/TAGs_and_HTML

Comment: well I understand your tip, but I still can't see how it would work, because a macro will run alone and I need to do a manual click on the words to get the text I need to "copy" or set variable... I don't know if you can understand what I'm saying, I believe would be better you check by yourself to understand it.

So instead of pass the game link, I'm gonna pass the alliance link that's where I have to click and open the game link of every user.

http://bit.ly/qc2EBM

By this link you can have access to the game link

Comment: So what I need to do it's click on first button "click" and choose my nickname on the combobox, check the checkbox to open next recruit user's link.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok, you want that code.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ResultsForm ATTR=NAME:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
URL GOTO=(Your form to fill)
```

After that you must get the tag position of your form then you will replace your text with this code:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:TestForm ATTR=NAME:Remarks CONTENT={{!VAR1}}

Whole code must be

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ResultsForm ATTR=NAME:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
URL GOTO=(Your form to fill)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:TestForm ATTR=NAME:Remarks CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

You can change `!EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO` to Yes, you can see what did you coppy at popup.

Edit the tag positions from reading [Html-Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128519/how-to-check-if-a-field-exists-using-imacro/6658174#6658174)

Or you can read [Tag-Html from wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAGs_and_HTML)

Recording a tab position isnt working well! Do not record it, write the position by yourself

Comment: well I understand your tip, but I still can't see how it would work, because a macro will run alone and I need to do a manual click on the words to get the text I need to "copy" or set variable

So instead of pass the game link, I'm gonna pass the alliance link that's where I have to click and open the game link of every user.

http://bit.ly/qc2EBM